# uploading JPEG using HTTP POST in C

Tags: c, linux, http-post, jpeg

I am trying to write a code to send a JPEG image to the server using HTTP POST in C. 
In my code, I am trying to construct the http post request (header, boundary, content etc...). The content is the JPEG image in this case. The image is corrupted on the server side. I am wondering what could be wrong in my code..

For those of you who may suggest using curl: I know curl may save me lot of work, but I am running this code in one of the linux box, which unfortunately does not support curl..

---

### UPDATE: I edited my code a little bit (code already updated below), and compared the two files on both client and server side, on the server side I found that all the 00 are missing... interesting fact but I still cannot figure out why it does this

```
#define MAXLINE 38400
#define FILESIZE 37632
#define MAXSUB  38016

char boundary[40] = "---------------------------";

ssize_t process_http(int sockfd, char *host, char *page, char *boundary, char *poststr)
{
    char sendline[MAXLINE + 1], recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    ssize_t n;
    snprintf(sendline, MAXLINE,
     "POST /%s HTTP/1.0\r\n"
     "Host: %s\r\n"
     "Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s\r\n"
     "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
     "%s", page, host, boundary, strlen(poststr), poststr);
    write(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline));
    while ((n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
    recvline[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s", recvline);
    }
    return n;
}
```

In MAIN:

```
//...
//socket initialization
//...


if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL){
   printf("File could not be opened\n");
   exit(1);
}
else{
   while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF){
        sprintf( &fileline[strlen(fileline)], "%c", ch );
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

snprintf(poststr, MAXSUB,
     "--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;"
     "name=\"file\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
     "%s\r\n\r\n"
     "--%s\r\n"
     "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"boxkey\"\r\n\r\n%s\r\n"
     "--%s--", boundary, filename, fileline, boundary, key, boundary);

//...
//then make socket connection...
//...

process_http(sockfd, hname, page, boundary, poststr);

//then close socket and return...
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you run tcpdump to capture the traffic that curl generates when uploading an image and compare it to the traffic your app generates. This has saved me countless lots of heartache

Comment: Is it just that one specific machine that doesn't support curl? Because it's available as standard on most distributions (and can of course be build from source if needed).

Comment: no, it is a embedded linux box... its kinda old and lack so many features.

Answer (score 1):

It's corrupt because you try to use string functions to add it to the packet you send. You have to remember that the C string functions uses the character `'\0'` (which in the ASCII alphabet is zero) is used as a string terminator. The first time the `snprintf` function finds a zero byte in the image data it thinks the "string" ends there.

It might also be your reading of the *binary* file, which you first open in *text*-mode, which means there might be newline-conversions. You also replace zeroes with newlines, which for binary data is also incorrect.

Comment: Hi, so what should I do in this case?

Comment: Don't use string handling functions for binary data. Keep track of sizes yourself and use the memory handling functions instead (e.g. `memcpy`)